# Обход двумерного массива спиралью по часовой стрелке

Tags: javascript, ruby, любой-язык, haskell, соревнование

### Задача соревнования:

Есть двумерный массив `N x N`. Нужно написать функцию, которая будет обходить двумерный массив спиралью по часовой стрелке, как показано на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### Пример `4x4`:

На входе есть двумерный массив:

```
entryArray = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [12, 13, 14, 5], [11, 16, 15, 6], [10, 9, 8, 7]]
```

На выходе одномерный массив после обхода:

```
exitArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Язык может быть любым. Основное условие: функция должна работать корректно для любого равностороннего двумерного массива, в том числе `1х1`, пустой массив возвращает пустой массив.

---

### Определение победителей:

Победитель будет определен по следующим параметрам:

1. Наименьшее количество символов кода
2. Количество голосов
3. Не более 2 правок после первого данного ответа

Ответ автора не учитывается при выборе победителя.

Победитель определится через 2 недели (26 октября).

Просьба указывать язык в заголовке ответа и количество символов минифицированной функции через запятую.

---

Хотелось бы увидеть решения на `Ruby`, `Haskell`, `Scala` и до бесконечности.
Большое спасибо за вашу активность!

---

### Вывод победителей:

```js
execute("ru.stackoverflow.com", "892196");
```

```css
.cssload-container,.cssload-cube{width:97px;height:97px;transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container,.cssload-cube,.cssload-half1,.cssload-half2{transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container{position:relative;margin:23px 84px;perspective:292px}.cssload-cube{animation:cube 11.5s forwards infinite;transform-origin:center 49px}.cssload-half1,.cssload-s1{top:0;transform-origin:50% 100%}.cssload-half1{height:39px;position:absolute;animation:half-fold 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-side{width:19px;height:19px;background:#ddd;position:absolute}.cssload-s1{left:39px;animation:s1ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s2,.cssload-s3,.cssload-s4{left:39px;transform-origin:50% 0}.cssload-s2{top:19px;animation:s2ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s3{top:39px;animation:s3ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s4{top:58px;animation:s4ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s5{left:19px;top:19px;transform-origin:100% 50%;animation:s5ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s6{left:58px;top:39px;transform-origin:0 50%;animation:s6ani 11.5s forwards infinite}@keyframes cube{0%,30%{transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}60%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}65%,70%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(180deg)}75%,80%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(1turn)}90%{transform:rotateX(0) rotate(0) rotate(0)}}@keyframes s1ani{0%{opacity:1;transform:translateY(0);background:#ddd}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(-90deg);background:#ddd}90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}@keyframes s2ani{0%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%,80%{background:#b4b4b4}65%{opacity:1;background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s3ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}20%,90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%{background:#969696}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s4ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%,to{opacity:0}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(90deg);background:#b4b4b4}80%{background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(90deg)}}@keyframes s5ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(-179deg)}20%{opacity:1;background:#ddd;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(90deg)}55%{background:#ddd}60%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{transform:rotateY(90deg);opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s6ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(179deg)}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(-90deg);background:#ddd}60%,80%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(-90deg)}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes half-fold{0%,50%{transform:rotateX(0)}60%,90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}
```

```html
<script src="https://mayorovp.github.io/codegolf/table-8c505e68f1349e4c69e7.js"></script>
<div class=cssload-container><div class=cssload-cube><div class=cssload-half1><div class="cssload-side cssload-s1"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s2"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s5"></div></div><div class=cssload-half2><div class="cssload-side cssload-s3"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s4"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s6"></div></div></div></div>
```

---

### Итоги соревнования:

**1 место** [Андрей NOP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218063/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-nop) с [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/896212/192664) на Haskell в 40 байт

**2 место** [Yauhen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/205894/yauhen) с [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/892196/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5/893895#893895) на Ruby в 59 байт

**3 место** [Let's say Pie](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/300000/lets-say-pie) с [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/892196/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5/896572#896572) на JavaScript в 81 байт

---

Всем большое спасибо за участие, все замечания будут учтены для последующих конкурсов.

Comment: *1. Наименьшее количество символов кода* То есть адептам брэйнфака можно даже не начинать...

Comment: @Akina если вы напишете на брейнфаке, то сообщество вас поддержит! Любой ответ ценен.

Comment: А что насчет задания массива? Должна ли программа его читать? Или просто функция для вывода заданного массива? В каком виде задается массив? Просто может оказаться, что сам ввод массива (или прошивка в программе) займет места больше, чем его вывод :)

Comment: Я вообще-то к тому, что заложенный в решение алгоритм на порядок ценнее его реализации на некоем языке, не говоря уж о количестве правок. Но это учитывается разве что косвенно во втором критерии...

Comment: @Akina Да и задача столько раз решена в Интернете, что...

Comment: Просто функция принимается в расчет, входной и выходной массив можете привести в качестве подтверждения.

Comment: Что значит "на входе" и "на выходе"? Речь идет о чтении стандартного выхода и выдаче на стандартный выход? Или можно вход зашивать прямо в программу? Но как тогда быть с выходом?

Comment: @AnT в функцию передаете равносторонний двумерный массив, а она возвращает одномерный.

Comment: @NikitaSmith, на php тоже сойдет? :D

Comment: Наименьшее кол-во строк кода странный критерий. Ведь он будет варьироваться от языка к языку, от фреймворка к фреймворку. Как уже заметили выше, то гораздо ценнее будет сам алгоритм и его качество по стандартным критериям:Память и быстродействие. Вот память и быстродействие- уже меньше будет меняться от языка к языку.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie почему нет?)

Comment: @iluxa1810 я на самом деле полностью разделяю вашу позицию,но чем лучше ваш алгоритм тем меньше кода. Один и тот же алгоритм будет разной длинный для каждого языка. Если мы предложите хорошее решение, то я не думаю, что вы не останетесь незамеченным. Если у вас есть свой способ оценки, я бы с удовольствием его посмотрел. Быстродействие тоже нельзя назвать идеальным критерием оценки, потому что разные структуры данных имеют разную "скорость обработки" в каждом языке, а в данном случае мы работаем конкретно с массивами.

Comment: @NikitaSmith, например, решения, которые будут использовать один и тот же алгоритм на АСМе и на чем-то новомодном будут в разы отличаться по кол-ву символов.

Comment: @NikitaSmith, иными словами: кол-во символов корректнее сравнивать в рамках одного конкретного языка, но не между языками.

Comment: @NikitaSmith => таблицу лидеров ИМХО сортировать нужно по Голосам, Языку,Размеру.

Comment: @NikitaSmith, можете написать мне в [вк](https://vk.com/wnull)?

Comment: @NikitaSmith, в правилах есть пункт, что нельзя править более N раз. Если я добавил код, а потом еще дополнительно через некоторое время прогнал через функцию минификации удаляя пробелы и поправил ответ- это считается за правку? Или за правку считается то, что если были изменены некоторые конструкции?

Comment: @iluxa1810 нет, правкой считается изменение логики.

Comment: @NikitaSmith, а если я изменил одну структуру на другую, так, что общий алгоритм не поменялся, но сократился на несколько символов? Например результирующий List заменил на массив, что бы сэкономить символы на конструировании объекта?

Comment: @iluxa1810 допустимо, изменение именно алгоритма считается за правку.

Comment: @iluxa1810, а откуда про строки кода? Не вижу ничего подобного в истории версий. В большинстве языков весь код можно записать в одну строку, так что действительно был бы неудачный критерий.

Comment: есть данное решение на asm коде, в разы короче чем то что есть,через 21 прерывания)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Haskell, 40

```
s[]=[];s(h:t)=h++(s$reverse$transpose t)
```

Решение эксплуатирует всё ту же идею отрезания первой строки от матрицы и поворота оставшегося куска против часовой стрелки.

https://ideone.com/FHeJAx

Answer (score 14):

## Python, <s>88</s> <s>65</s> 60

```
f=lambda m:m and m.pop(0)+f([list(x)for x in zip(*m)][::-1])
```

Первый раз пишу на Python, поэтому пока не знаю приемов для сокращения (длины) кода.

Возникла следующая идея: берем матрицу, отрезаем от нее первую строку, оставшуюся часть поворачиваем против часовой стрелки на 90 градусов и рекурсивно применяем этот же алгоритм. В итоге потребовалось лишь выбрать ЯП, умеющий такие операции из коробки, им оказался Python ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

https://ideone.com/5qasui

Бонусом — алгоритм работает с любыми прямоугольными матрицами (не только с квадратными).

Comment: У меня Ваш вариант весит 89 байт (89 символов в utf8, ведь так?), а если содержимое f изменить на `return m if not m else m.pop(0)+f(list(list(x) for x in zip(*m))[::-1])`, то 83 байта.

Comment: Да не, 88 вроде. Символов не из ASCII здесь нет, поэтому в utf8 тоже будет 88. Или вы еще перевод строки в конце считаете? За такую запись метода — спасибо, буду копить варианты сокращения, т.к. ТС ограничил количество попыток правки :)

Comment: Да, действительно, я его посчитал (по ошибке), теперь понял. За запись - пожалуйста) Предполагаю, и правда, можно её ещё сократить

Comment: Кстати, можно писать `[list(x) for x in zip(*m)]` вместо `list(list(x) for x in zip(*m))`

Comment: `m if not m else m...` — какой корявый тернарный оператор в python :)

Comment: @Anton, можно переписать в виде однострочной лямбды и получить 71 символ в итоге

Comment: Меньше, ведь после двоеточия пробел необязателен) И убрав при этом not: m if not m else ... заменить на ... if m else m

Comment: @АндрейNOP тоже решил на питоне написать, на основе твоего решения.  Можешь взглянуть)

Comment: @Anton, ага, поудалял чуть пробелов, 65 символов в итоге пока. Отредактировал ответ. Пусть будет первая правка

Answer (score 13):

Из-за этого, гм... требования "кто меньше" рождаются вот такие монстры...

## C++, 155 байт

232 байта

```
#define c(i,j) )std::cout<<m[i][j]<<" ";
using M=std::vector<std::vector<int>>;void s(M&m,int h){int i,n=m.size(),k=n-h-1;if(n>2*h){for(i=h;i<=k;c(h,i++)for(i=h+1;i<=k;c(i++,k)for(i=k-1;i>=h;c(k,i--)for(i=k-1;i>h;c(i--,h)s(m,h+1);}}
```

Если разрешить (и не считать) достаточно стандартное

```
using namespace std;
```

то получим 217 байт...

Вот тест для четного и нечетного N: https://ideone.com/OEHTLS

Если надо именно запихнуть в массив - на 14 байт больше:

```
#define c(i,j) )v.push_back(m[i][j]);
using V=std::vector<int>;
using M=std::vector<V>;void s(M&m,V&v,int h){int i,n=m.size(),k=n-h-1;if(n>2*h){for(i=h;i<=k;c(h,i++)for(i=h+1;i<=k;c(i++,k)for(i=k-1;i>=h;c(k,i--)for(i=k-1;i>h;c(i--,h)s(m,v,h+1);}}
```

## Первое дозволенное изменение :) для запихивания в массив

230 байт

```
#define c(k,r,c) for(i=0;i<k;++i)v.push_back(m[r][c]);
using V=std::vector<int>;void s(std::vector<V>&m,V&v,int h){int r=h,c=h,i,n=m.size(),k=n-2*h-1;if(!k)c(1,r,c)else if(k>0){c(k,r,c++)c(k,r++,c)c(k,r,c--)c(k,r--,c)s(m,v,h+1);}}
```

Проверка - https://ideone.com/86YkY4

## Второе дозволенное изменение

Как с оптимизацией - менять надо алгоритм. Меняем... получаем 196 байт.

```
using V=std::vector<int>;void s(std::vector<V>&m,V&v,int n,int h){int r=h,c=h,i=0,j,l=n-2*h-1;if(l>-1){do{v.push_back(m[r][c]);l?(j=i/l)<1?c++:j<2?r++:j<3?c--:r--:l;}while(++i<4*l);s(m,v,n,h+1);}}
```

https://ideone.com/rDXdbh

Но менять-то можно не только алгоритм, но и используемую структуру данных! Перейдем к `int**`, благо условие задачи ничего не говорит о том, *как именно* следует создавать массив. Тогда мы получаем окончательное решение в 155 байт

```
void s(int**m,int*v,int n,int h){int r=h,c=h,i=0,j,l=n-2*h-1;if(l>-1){do{*v++=m[r][c];l?(j=i/l)<1?c++:j<2?r++:j<3?c--:r--:l;}while(++i<4*l);s(m,v,n,h+1);}}
```

https://ideone.com/vukXQG

для которого просто надо готовить входной массив несколько иначе.

На этом, пожалуй, и остановимся.

P.S. Вообще-то в таких соревнованиях нужны какие-то иные правила... Потому что одно дело - писать алгоритм с нуля и другое, немного утрируя - вызвать готовую библиотечную функцию. Или использовать более "краткий" язык - опять же, утрируя, представим язык, в котором инкремент выглядит исключительно как `summation(a,1)` и никак иначе :(

Answer (score 11):

### Python 2, <s>60</s> 59 байт

Решил разбавить немного `python`'ом.

Логика как у [@Андрей NOP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218063/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-nop), но код короче:

```
def f(a):return list(a[0])+f(zip(*a[1:])[::-1])if a else []
```

---

### Подтверждение:

https://ideone.com/4Xmy7W

---

### Небольшое добавление:

Пример выше реализован для Python второй версии. Для того чтобы функция работала должным образом в 3 версии нужно обернуть `zip` в `list`: `list(zip(...))`. Разница в том, что во второй версии `zip` возвращает список, а в третьей возвращает итерируемый объект.

Comment: В третьем питоне почему-то не работает, в чем разница?

Comment: @АндрейNOP дело в том что во второй версии питона zip возвращает список, а в третьем итерированный объект) оберни zip в list и будет работать в 3.

Answer (score 10):

## JS, 125 символов

```
function f(a){for(var b=[];a.length;)b.push(...a.shift()),a.map(c=>b.push(c.pop())),a.reverse().map(c=>c.reverse());return b}
```

---

### Доказательство корректности:

```js
function spiralRound(entryArray) {
  var exitArray = [];
  //Повторяем действие пока entryArray не останентся пустым
  while (entryArray.length) {
    //Добавление в exitArray первого вложенного массива из entryArray. 
    //shift() возвращает первый вложенный массив и удаляет его из entryArray.
    exitArray.push(...entryArray.shift());
 
    //Добавляем в exitArray каждый последний элемент из каждого оставщегося массива в entryArray.
    //pop() возвращает последний элемент массива и удаляет его из исходного 
    entryArray.map(row => exitArray.push(row.pop()));
 
    //Разворачиваем оставщийся массив на 180 градусов
    entryArray.reverse().map(row => row.reverse());
  }
  //Возвращаем результат
  return exitArray;
}

let testArray = [];
console.log("0x0:" + spiralRound(testArray));

testArray = [
  [1]
];
console.log("1x1:" + spiralRound(testArray));

testArray = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4]
];
console.log("2x2:" + spiralRound(testArray));

testArray = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [12, 13, 14, 5],
  [11, 16, 15, 6],
  [10, 9, 8, 7]
]
console.log("4x4:" + spiralRound(testArray));

testArray = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 5, 7, 8],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 5, 7, 8],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 5, 7, 8],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 5, 7, 8],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 5, 7, 8],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 5, 7, 8],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 5, 7, 8],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 5, 7, 8],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 5, 7, 8],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 5, 7, 8],
]
console.log("10x10:" + spiralRound(testArray));
```

Comment: Можете чуть-чуть расписать идею решения и как оно работает? Не совсем догоняю его...

Comment: @АндрейNOP добавил пояснение в код

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста троеточие перед a.shift()

Comment: @axmed2004, почитайте про оператор расширения

Answer (score 9):

## PHP 7.4, 124

```
$f=fn($a,$f)=>$a?[...array_shift($a),...$f(array_reverse($a?next($a)?array_map(null,...$a):array_chunk($a[0],1):$a),$f)]:$a;
```

https://3v4l.org/JDGfH

Comment: Долларовый ад. Одних долларов — 58 штук... :(

Comment: @Андрей NOP, мультимиллионер)))) а так, согласен,  намного короче вышло бы, но что поделать :)

Answer (score 8):

## JS, <s>121</s> <s>107</s> 81

```
f=b=>b[0]?[...b.shift(),...f(b[0]?b[0].map((d,e)=>b.map(g=>g[e])).reverse():b)]:b
```

Правка без изменения алгоритма, с  учетом замечаний и предложений @Андрей NOP. Функцию переделал в лямбду, а также заменил `b.length` на `b[0]`, и `[]` заменил на `b`.

Демо:

```js
f = b => b[0] 
    ? [...b.shift(), ...f(b[0] ? b[0].map((d, e) => b.map(g => g[e])).reverse() : b)] 
    : b

console.log([
    [], 
    [[1]], 
    [[1, 2], [4, 3]], 
    [[1, 2, 3], [8, 9, 4], [7, 6, 5]], 
    [[1, 2, 3, 4], [12, 13, 14, 5], [11, 16, 15, 6], [10, 9, 8, 7]], 
    [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 11, 12, 5],[9, 8, 7, 6]] 
].map(f))
```

Comment: В лямбду не превратить?

Comment: Вместо `b.length` можно написать `!b`, ну и вместо `[]` — `b`

Comment: Да вроде работает лямбда, заменить `function f(b){return ... }` на `f=b=>...`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, лямбда сработала, а на счет `b.length` -> `!b` не уверен

Comment: @АндрейNOP, подумал, можно просто заменить `b.length` на `b[0]`

Comment: Хм, да, в JS не работает, похоже любой массив возвращает `true`

Comment: `b[0]` тоже нельзя, т.к. если там будет лежать 0 — то тоже вернет `false`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, тогда стоит оставить `b.length`?

Comment: пока другого варианта в голову не приходит

Comment: С другой стороны по условию в `b[0]` не может лежать `0`, т.к. у нас массив массивов и у нас либо он пустой `[]`, либо в первом элементе лежит какой-то массив `[[0]]`, число лежать не может. А для `[[0]]` работает нормально

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84816/discussion-between-lets-say-pie-and--nop).

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, <s>61</s> 59

```
def f(a) a.empty? ? [] : a.shift+f(a.transpose.reverse) end
```

https://ideone.com/SYmf7W

Comment: Можно еще, вроде, поудалять пробелов: https://ideone.com/1iLRAX

Comment: @АндрейNOP Вернуть `a` вместо `[]`, если `а` пустой массив - хорошее замечание(-1 символ). А вот пробелы удалять... Хотелось бы, чтобы код читался легко. Это же Ruby, а не JS, где лишний пробел в скрипте - лишний байт переданный на клиент.

Comment: Ну, у нас код-гольф, а не реальное приложение :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Значит есть небольшая фора в несколько символов :)

Answer (score 7):

## C#, <s>320</s> 280

```
static int[]f(int[,]a){var r=new List<int>();var n=a.GetLength(0);int j=-1,i=0;bool h=true;bool d=false;int c=0;int p=n;int max=n;for(var cnt=1;cnt<=a.Length;cnt++){i=h?i:!d?++i:--i;j=!h?j:!d?++j:--j;p--;r.Add(a[i,j]);if(p<=0){h=!h;if((c+1)%2==0){d=!d;}if(cnt==n||c>1&&(c+1)%2!=0){--max;}p=max;c++;}}return r.ToArray();}
```

Потестить можно вот тут на [deck.net](https://deck.net/981288b58145d16e1772f1bcedd0aeea)

---

```
int[]F(int[,]a){var n=a.GetLength(0);var r=new int[n*n];int j=-1,i=0;var h=true;var d=!h;int o=0;int p=n;intm=n;for(varc=1;c<=a.Length;c++){p--;r[c-1]=a[h?i:!d?++i:--i,!h?j:!d?++j:--j];if(p<=0&&a.Length!=2){h=!h;if((o+1)%2==0)d=!d;if(c==n||o>1&&(o+1)%2!=0)--m;p=m;o++;}}return r;}
```

Внес небольшие исправления не меняя алгоритм, что бы уменьшить длину кода

Потестить можно вот тут на [deck.net](https://deck.net/81260cc04f306801841d29fa7dda4121)

---

Смысл в том, что я делаю реверс булевых флагов, которые показывают какие индексы в какую сторону двигать и на основании этого я обхожу массив.

Вроде бы, это должно быть эффективно нежеле алгоритмы, через повороты матриц, которые ИМХО будут не так эффективны на больших матрицах.

Comment: Ну тут как раз смысл в более коротком, а не более эффективном коде (на то он и [tag:код-гольф]). По вашему коду: можно убрать `static`; я бы попробовал использовать не list, а все-таки массив — вызов конструктора короче, не нужен `toArray`, но придется завести `counter` и добавлять как `r[++counter]=a[i,j]`. Ну и по мелочам: `{d=!d;}` -> `d=!d;`; `bool` -> `var`; `max` -> `m`; `int c=0;int p=n;int max=n;` -> `int c=0,p=n,max=n;` и т.д. байтов 50 можно выиграть

Comment: @АндрейNOP, попробую.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, поправил. Интересно, можно ли еще с помощью LINQ это все упростит или сделать алтернативное короткое решение...

Answer (score 6):

## C, <s>193</s> <s>191</s> <s>178</s> 175 байт

```
int f(int n,int a[][n],int*b){int d=0,j=0,k=0,s=0,m=n-1,f=0;for(int i=0;i<n*n;i++,s++){if(s==m){d++,d%=4,s=0,f++;if(f%3==0)m--,f=1;}b[i]=!d?a[j][k++]:d==1?a[j++][k]:d==2?a[j][k--]:a[j--][k];}}
```

Проверить код можно на [Ideone](https://ideone.com/eiTw4K).

**Первая правка**

Сделал все переменные кроме `m` статическими, чтобы избавится от инициализации нулями, а также вынес объявление переменной `i` из `for`:

```
int f(int n,int a[][n],int *b){static int d,j,k,s,f,i;int m=n-1;for(;i<n*n;i++,s++){if(s==m){d++;d%=4;s=0;f++;if(f%3==0){m--;f=1;}}b[i]=!d?a[j][k++]:d==1?a[j++][k]:d==2?a[j][k--]:a[j--][k];}}
```

Снова [ссылка на Ideone](https://ideone.com/3GvmLI).

**Вторая правка**

Убрал ненужные фигурные скобки, заменил `if` на тернарный оператор, убрал явный тип `int` в объявлении статических переменных:

```
int f(int n,int a[][n],int*b){static d,j,k,s,f,i;int m=n-1;for(;i<n*n;i++,s++)s==m?d++,d%=4,s=0,f++,f%3==0?m--,f=1:m:m,b[i]=!d?a[j][k++]:d==1?a[j++][k]:d==2?a[j][k--]:a[j--][k];}
```

Проверить третью версию можно [здесь](https://ideone.com/652QBP).

**Третья правка**

Я так понимаю, правки, *не изменяющие алгоритм*, не считаются «исправлениями», так что внесу еще одну коррективу в код: сделаю `m` статической и внесу ее инициализацию в `for`:

```
int f(int n,int a[][n],int*b){static d,j,k,s,f,i,m;for(m=n-1;i<n*n;i++,s++)s==m?d++,d%=4,s=0,f++,f%3==0?m--,f=1:m:m,b[i]=!d?a[j][k++]:d==1?a[j++][k]:d==2?a[j][k--]:a[j--][k];}
```

[Проверям](https://ideone.com/7my1YS) четвертую версию.

Answer (score 6):

## JS, 133 байта (125 если допустимо убрать `let`)

```
let f=e=>{let t=[],f=r=0,h=-1,n=l=e[0].length;for(;n;)f?f<2?r++:f<3?h--:r--:h++,t.push(e[r][h]),--l||(f%2||n--,f=++f%4,l=n);return t}
```

Запоминаем направление и число шагов до поворота по часовой стрелке. После поворота обновляем число шагов до следующего поворота. Поворот вниз и вверх (после движения вправо и влево, соответственно) уменьшают число шагов до очередного поворота. Заканчиваем перебор если шаги уменьшать больше некуда.

Тесты прилагаются; для `N` от `0` до `4`.

```js
let f = a => {
  let
  R = [], // result

  // directions
  // 0 - right
  // 1 - down
  // 2 - left
  // 3 - up
  d =

  r = 0, // row (y)
  c = -1, // col (x)

  L = // row (col) length
  l = // local length
  a[0].length;

  for (;L;) { // while (L) {
    !d    ? c++ : // if (d === 0) { c++; }
    d < 2 ? r++ : // else if (d === 1) { r++; }
    d < 3 ? c-- : // else if (d === 2) { c--; }
    r--;          // else { r--; }

    R.push(a[r][c]);

    --l || (        // if (--l === 0) {
      d % 2 || L--, //   if (d === 0 || d === 2) { L--; }
      d = ++d % 4,  //   if (++d > 3) { d = 0; }
      l = L
    )               // }
  }

  return R;
};


let tests = [];
tests.push(
  [
    [[]],
    []
  ]
);
tests.push(
  [
    [[1]],
    [1]
  ]
);
tests.push(
  [
    [
      [1, 2],
      [4, 3]
    ],
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
  ]
);
tests.push(
  [
    [
      ["a", "b"],
      ["d", "c"]
    ],
    ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
  ]
);
tests.push(
  [
    [
      [1, 2, 3],
      [8, 9, 4],
      [7, 6, 5]
    ],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  ]
);
tests.push(
  [
    [
      [ 1,  2,  3, 4],
      [12, 13, 14, 5],
      [11, 16, 15, 6],
      [10,  9,  8, 7]
    ],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
  ]
);

for (let expected, actual, i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
  expected = tests[i][1].join(", ");
  actual = f(tests[i][0]).join(", ");
  if (expected === actual) {
    console.log(`${i}: OK`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${i}: FAIL`);
    console.log(`expected: [${expected}]`);
    console.log(`actual: [${actual}]`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## Java, 300

Сделано по первому алгоритму из моего [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/894545/300000), оставленного ранее.

```
static int[] f(int a[][]){int i,d=0,k=0,l=0,n=a[0].length,m=a.length;int[]r=new int[m*n];if(a==null)return r;while(k<m&&l<n){for(i=l;i<n;++i)r[d++]=a[k][i];k++;for(i=k;i<m;++i)r[d++]=a[i][n-1];n--;if(k<m)for(i=n-1;i>=l;--i)r[d++]=a[m-1][i];m--;if(l<n)for(i=m-1;i>=k;--i)r[d++]=a[i][l];l++;}return r;}
```

https://ideone.com/SvEX11

Comment: Пробелы местами лишние. `int[]f(int[]a[])` вместо `int[] f(int a[][])` и сразу -2 символа.

Answer (score 5):

## C#, <s>202</s> <s>153</s> 341 байт

```
void Spiral(int[,]a){int n=a.GetLength(0);int c=n;int v=-n;int s=-1;do{v=-1*v/n;for(int i=0; i<c;i++){s+=v;Write(a[s/n,s%n]+" ");}v*=n;c--;for(int i=0;i<c;i++){s+=v;Write(a[s/n,s%n]+" ");}}while (c>0);}
```

Проверить код можно на [deck.net](https://deck.net/d330bcc8a9295542006ba3fba732c773)

**Первое исправление**

Уменьшил код за счет методов расширения: **<s>153</s> байт**

Проверить код можно на [deck.net](https://deck.net/8ccf7282af1577b1a08aed59d995f590)

**Второе исправление**
Размер кода **341 байт**

Учтены замечания @Андрей NOP

```
Int32[] Spiral_Min(Int32[,]arr){List<Int32>list=new List<Int32>();Int32 n=arr.GetLength(0);Int32 count=n;Int32 value=-n;Int32 sum=-1;do{value=-1*value/n;for(Int32 i=0;i<count;i++){sum+=value;list.Add(arr[sum/n,sum%n]);}value*=n;count--;for(Int32 i=0;i<count;i++){sum+=value;list.Add(arr[sum/n,sum%n]);}}while(count>0);return list.ToArray();}
```

Проверить код можно на [deck.net](https://deck.net/041960e826a057bcdde66c5d2e2c1782)

Comment: По условию функция должна возвращать одномерный массив, а не на консоль что-то выводить, ну и в зачет идет весь вспомогательный код, т. ч. хак с выносом кусков кода в методы не прокатит — их длина тоже должна подсчитываться

Comment: учту замечания!

Comment: Зачем Вы пишите `Int32`? Ещё бы писали `System.Int32`) У Вас же есть стандартное сокращение, коие на 2 символа короче - `int`

Comment: привычка)))))))

Answer (score 4):

## JS, 156

```
function g(n,u){b.push(a[n][u]),a[n][u]=null,!a[n][u+1]||0!=n&&a[n-1][u]||g(n,++u),a[n+1]&&a[n+1][u]&&g(++n,u),a[n][u-1]&&g(n,--u),0<n&&a[n-1][u]&&g(--n,u)}
```

В минифицированном представлении используется рекурсия. Пример вызова в этом случае:

```
 a=[[1, 2, 3, 4], [12, 13, 14, 5], [11, 16, 15, 6], [10, 9, 8, 7]]
 b=[]
 g(0,0);
```

Развернутый алгоритм:

```
    //Implementation
    function Position(x, y) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }

            function getArray(array) {
                var res = [];
                var position = getNext(0, -1);
                while (position) {
                    res.push(array[position.x][position.y]);
                    array[position.x][position.y] = undefined;
                    position = getNext(position.x, position.y);
                }
                return res;
                
                function getNext(x, y) {
                    if (array[x][y + 1] && (!array[x - 1] || !array[x - 1][y])) return new Position(x, y + 1);
                    if (array[x + 1] && array[x + 1][y]) return new Position(x + 1, y);
                    if (array[x][y - 1]) return new Position(x, y - 1);
                    if (array[x - 1] && array[x - 1][y]) return new Position(x - 1, y);
                    return undefined;
                }
            }

    //Example
    var entryArray = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [12, 13, 14, 5], [11, 16, 15, 6], [10, 9, 8, 7]]
    var result = getArray(entryArray);
```

ПС Обратите внимание здесь не используются готовые инкапсулированные алгиритмы в других функциях для работы с массивами, все на нативном уровне ;)

Comment: Попробуй минифицировать функцию, посчитай сколько знаков.

Comment: Только увидел что код должен быть короче. Думаю алгоритм можно ещё оптимизировать в этом плане

Answer (score 4):

### PHP, 225 байт

```
function f(array $a):array{if(empty($a))return [];$r=$a[0];$l=count($r);$x=$l-1;$y=$i=0;$s=[[0,1],[-1,0],[0,-1],[1,0]];for(;$l>0;$l-=$i++%2){for($j=$l-1;$j>0;$j--){$x+=$s[$i%4][0];$y+=$s[$i%4][1];$r[]=$a[$y][$x];}}return $r;}
```

---

### Пример:

https://ideone.com/xdZo8E

Comment: Можно еще упростить до `203` байт: https://ideone.com/fZRr4C

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 256 символов

```
function z(b){var c=b.length;if(0==c)return[];if(1==c)return b[0];var d=b[0].slice(0,-1),e=b.slice(0,-1).map(i=>i[c-1]),f=b[c-1].slice(1).reverse(),g=b.slice(1).map(i=>i[0]).reverse(),h=b.slice(1,-1).map(i=>i.slice(1,-1));return[].concat(d,e,f,g,z(h))}
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
function func(array) {
  var size = array.length;

  if (size == 0)
    return [];

  if (size == 1)
    return array[0];

  var top = array[0].slice(0, -1);
  var right = array.slice(0, -1).map(a => a[size - 1]);
  var bottom = array[size - 1].slice(1).reverse();
  var left = array.slice(1).map(a => a[0]).reverse();
  var inner = array.slice(1, -1).map(a => a.slice(1, -1));

  return [].concat(top, right, bottom, left, func(inner));
}

entryArray = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [12, 13, 14, 5],
  [11, 16, 15, 6],
  [10, 9, 8, 7]
];

console.log(func(entryArray));
```

Comment: не работает для матриц других размеров отличных от 4 на 4. по условию должно работать для любых равносторонних

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, 252 байта

```
function f(b){var c=b.length;if(0==c)return[];if(1==c)return b[0];var d=b[0].slice(0,-1),e=b.slice(0,-1).map(j=>j[c-1]),g=b[c-1].slice(1).reverse(),h=b.slice(1).map(j=>j[0]).reverse(),i=b.slice(1,-1).map(j=>j.slice(1,-1));return[].concat(d,e,g,h,f(i))}
```

---

### Подтверждение корректности:

```js
function f(array) {
  var size = array.length;

  if (size == 0)
    return [];

  if (size == 1)
    return array[0];

  var top = array[0].slice(0, -1);
  var right = array.slice(0, -1).map(a => a[size - 1]);
  var bottom = array[size - 1].slice(1).reverse();
  var left = array.slice(1).map(a => a[0]).reverse();
  var inner = array.slice(1, -1).map(a => a.slice(1, -1));

  return [].concat(top, right, bottom, left, f(inner));
}

console.log(f([]))
console.log(f([
  [1]
]))
console.log(f([
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4]
]))
console.log(f([
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [12, 13, 14, 5],
  [11, 16, 15, 6],
  [10, 9, 8, 7]
]));
```

Comment: На будущее, оформляйте ответ согласно требованиям

Comment: @NikitaSmith ладно.

Answer (score 3):

**C++, 216 bytes**

```
void F(int**v,int*o,int S){int s=0,i=0;--S;while(S>0){for(int c=s;c<=S;++c)o[i++]=v[s][c];for(int c=s+1;c<=S;++c)o[i++]=v[c][S];for(int c=S-1;c>=s;--c)o[i++]=v[S][c];for(int c=S-1;c>=s+1;--c)o[i++]=v[c][s];--S;++s;}}
```

Простой и интуитивный алгоритм без рекурсии или поворотов.

Развернутая реализация для демонстрации алгоритма:

```
void spiral_traverse(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& v) {
    int size = v[0].size();
    int start = 0, end = size - 1;
    while (end > 0) {
        for (int c = start; c <= end; ++c) {
            std::cout << v[start][c] << ' ';
        }
        for (int c = start + 1; c <= end; ++c) {
            std::cout << v[c][end] << ' ';
        }
        for (int c = end - 1; c >= start; --c) {
            std::cout << v[end][c] << ' ';
        }
        for (int c = end - 1; c >= start + 1; --c) {
            std::cout << v[c][start] << ' ';
        }
        --end; ++start;
    }
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/Eqo5aA)