# Код-гольф: Обход двумерного массива змейкой

Tags: любой-язык, соревнование

### Задача соревнования:

Имеется двумерный массив `N x N`. Нужно написать функцию обхода двумерного массива змейкой от правого ребра. Пример на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### Пример двумерного массива:

На входе имеется следующий массив:

```
input = [[4, 3, 2, 1], [5, 6, 7, 8], [12, 11, 10, 9], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

На выходе одномерный массив после обхода:

```
output = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Может использоваться любой язык.

**Основное условие**: функция должна работать корректно для любого равностороннего двумерного массива.

Указывать название языка в заголовке ответа и количество символов минифицированной версии функции через запятую.

Победителем станет тот, кто напишет ее за меньшее количество символов. За это он получает 300 репутации. Победитель определится через 2 недели (**12 января**).

Ответ автора не учитывается при выборе победителя. Желаю удачи :)

## Таблица лидеров:

```js
execute("ru.stackoverflow.com", 926927);
```

```html
<script src="https://mayorovp.github.io/codegolf/table-8c505e68f1349e4c69e7.js"></script>
```

---

## Победители:

1 место: [Haskell - 39 (@АндрейNOP)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/926950/285292)

2 место: [JavaScript - 40 (@Groxan)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/928451/285292)

3 место: [Groovy - 42 (@Nick)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/931150/285292)

Всем огромное спасибо за участие и интересные решения ;)

Comment: Ну вот, опять - "меньшее количество символов" независимо от языка. Участвовать с C/C++ - никакого смысла...

Comment: @Harry, что вы предлагаете? Поменять условия и выбирать самое уникальное решение? :)

Comment: Я не предлагаю, а информирую :) Да и потом, зачем - уникальное? Например, самое быстрое :)

Comment: @Harry, спасибо, идея мне понравилась, поменяю правила)

Comment: Как вы планируете сравнивать различные решения (на разных языках) на скорость? ;)

Comment: @MaxU, пожалуй я вернусь к правилам кода-гольфа, как-то не подумал... Спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Подсчёт количества символов ведётся только для "прохода по массиву"? То есть учитывается ли ввод данных в массив, вывод массива на экран (и нужен ли он)? И ещё вопрос: N выбирается автором ответа? Если да, то допустимы ли N=0 и степени двойки?

Comment: @cppquestions, подсчет символов самой функции, ввод и вывод данных в массив не нужен. В примерах использовать функцию на заполненном массиве. N определяется автоматически, в зависимости от массива

Comment: @Let'ssayPie только символов тела функции? Можно ли тогда делать что-нибудь вне её?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie ну на C и C++, например, можно задефайнить всё что угодно вне функции и в теле функции оставить 1 символ, который препроцессор заменит на нужный код извне тела :)

Comment: @cppquestions, посмотрите [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/892347/285292) с похожего соревнования

Comment: @MaxU Но ведь на длину текста он же как-то сравнивает? :) Я потому и предложил (не всерьез, кстати, потому и смайлик) скорость - что C/C++ при этом будет в заведомо выигрышном положении :)

Comment: связанный вопрос [creating a spiral array in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36834505/4279)

Comment: Раз любой, тогда можно и несуществующий (пока) язык snake. В нём определёно префикс `s`, который решает вышеуказанную задачу. Код для прохождения массива NxN кодируется как `sN`

Comment: Тоже поддерживаю, т.к. задания, порой, интересные и соревновательный интерес подстёгивает, но на кол-во символов не каждый язык способен соревноваться

Comment: @Isaev, чем каждый язык способен посоревноваться?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie Ни чем, наверное... В силу своей специфики, нельзя сравнивать несравнимое... Можно соревноваться в одном языке в чем угодно, но в разных только очень условно

Comment: @PavelMayorov, таблица сломалась похоже

Comment: @АндрейNOP можешь сказать что именно там не работает? А также свой браузер.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, изначально тоже заметил поломку, неправильный рейтинг был, и у некоторых выводилось N/A. Но сейчас все в порядке.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, сейчас нормально стало, до этого ответ *C#, 201* ставил на первое место

Comment: @Let'ssayPie потому что надо последнюю версию скрипта использовать, а не устаревшую :-)

Comment: @АндрейNOP я уж было подумал, что это из-за моей правки что-то сломалось, а вы про старую версию... Не пугайте так!

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну как раз после правки я и смотрел

Comment: @АндрейNOP это странно... Там же стоит преобразование к числу, только что еще раз проверил.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie считается ли [][](массив массивов) и [,](двумерный массив) одним и тем же?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie касательно 'чем каждый язык способен посоревноваться?' Можно поставить все языки в одинаковые рамки, сказав, что можно пользоваться такими-то такими-то операторами, тем самым искусственно поставив все языки в одинаковые рамки. А то получается, что в одном языке прямо "из коробки" есть нужные функции и он может решить все одной строчкой. Например, хочешь решать через Reverse? Будь добр сам ее дополнительно реализовать и как следствии код между языки будет ~ одинаковым по размеру.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie и еще вопрос: а обязательно возвращать массив из функции? Например, в C# я могу вернуть IEnumerable, который вызывающая сторона одним движением руки может кастануть в массив.

Comment: @iluxa1810, изначально придумано так, чтобы возвращал массив, увы.

Comment: Забавно, как просьба "Если это неприемлемо, скажите" была молча проигнорирована...

Comment: @Groxan, хотел уделить этому внимание позже, с телефона не очень удобно в дороге. Спасибо.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Haskell, 39 <s>40 42</s>

```
r=reverse;s[]=[];s(h:t)=r h++s(map r t)
```

https://ideone.com/JYttmr

Answer (score 12):

## Python, 56

```
f=lambda l:sum([x[::i%2*2-1]for i,x in enumerate(l)],[])
```

[Спасибо @АндрейNOP за подсказку!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/926927/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84-%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9/926965?noredirect=1#comment1537957_926965)

## Python, 60

```
f=lambda l:sum([[x[::-1],x][i&1]for i,x in enumerate(l)],[])
```

https://ideone.com/JPyzUQ (эта версия с лямбда функцией была любезно предоставлена @Let's say Pie)

---

**Попытка 2:** инвалидирована по причине неправильного оформления - решение должно быть реализовано как функция

## Python, 49

```
sum([[x[::-1],x][i&1]for i,x in enumerate(l)],[])
```

https://ideone.com/WdHq4n

PS [@КириллМалышев подсказал как можно сократить код еще на 6 символов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/926927/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84-%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9/926965?noredirect=1#comment1533102_926965) - **спасибо!!**

---

**Попытка 1:**

## Python, 55

```
sum([x if i&1 else x[::-1] for i,x in enumerate(l)],[])
```

https://ideone.com/2hoF3P

Comment: Если сильно постараться, то можно и [до 53](https://ideone.com/ZZKko4) сократить :D

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, я пока не вижу где можно урезать два символа... ;)

Comment: if else поменять на and or и перед фором пробел убрать :)

Comment: sum([[x[::-1],x][i&1]for i,x in enumerate(l)],[]) Тернарник отлично сворачивается в список

Comment: @КириллМалышев, красиво! :) Может оформите как ответ?

Comment: @MaxU, я думаю это вам стоит дополнить ответ, а его упомянуть за помощь :)

Comment: @MaxU, хочу напомнить, что нужно написать отдельную функцию/лямбду для обработки массива, только её количество символов будет считаться. В вашем случае нужно сделать преобразование. [Пример 60 символов](https://ideone.com/JPyzUQ)

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, исправил, спасибо за [код](https://ideone.com/JPyzUQ) ! :-) Тогда версии с Octave и Numpy (мою) тоже надо инвалидировать, т.к. там тоже не реализованы функции...

Comment: `[x[::-1],x][i&1]` => `x[::i%2*2-1]`, выигрываем 4 символа

Comment: @АндрейNOP, отличная идея, спасибо! :)

Answer (score 11):

## Python, 43

```
f=lambda m,a=-1:m and m.pop(0)[::a]+f(m,-a)
```

https://ideone.com/fQVgtD

Answer (score 10):

## Octave, 47

```matlab
@(l,b=l(1:2:end,:)=fliplr(l(1:2:end,:)))l'(:)';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcxNCgIxFAPgq2Q3LbyFef63FLyHuKg6glBGUfH6NbNzmeQjj8unfsdeUXBcG1aGpcENzNgYtoadYa@4yKB2ClCCM5GhEKUoRjmXczmX8/lJznnqh9DsXFpg8jROV0ux3Nr92V7hv4uxDSHFIfc6vUON/Qc)

Если разрешить возвращать не вектор-строку, а вектор-столбец, сокращается на 1 символ:

## Octave, 46

```matlab
@(l,b=l(1:2:end,:)=fliplr(l(1:2:end,:)))l'(:);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcxNCgIxFAPgq2RnC29hnv8tBe8hLqqOIJRRRvH6NbNzmeQjz@unfodeUXDaGNaGlcENzNgadoa94aC4zKB2ClCCM5GhEKUoRjmXczmX8/lJznnux9DsUlpg8jSMN0ux3Nvj1abw38XYFiHF3Ov4DjX2Hw)

Прошлый вариант без анонимной функции:

## Octave, 40

```matlab
l(1:2:end,:)=fliplr(l(1:2:end,:));l'(:)'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TczNCsJAEAPgV8mtuzAHM/52lz6JeBBbQRhUSunrr@nNY5KPfB7LfZ1aYMD1aDgY9gY3sOJkOBsuhl5xV0HtFKAENyJDIUpRjHIu53Iu59uTnPPWIrF4md6jlTw84/WNOf13uUaXSu5a@wE)

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript, 38

Данный код работает в Firefox, но не работает на V8 (из-за специфичного алгоритма сортировки). Если это неприемлемо, скажите =)

```js
f=a=>a.flatMap((x,i)=>x.sort(_=>~i&1))

console.log(f([[4,3,2,1],[5,6,7,8],[12,11,10,9],[13,14,15,16]]));
```

---

## JavaScript, 40

```js
f=a=>a.flatMap((x,i)=>i%2?x:x.reverse())

console.log(f([[4,3,2,1],[5,6,7,8],[12,11,10,9],[13,14,15,16]]));
```

Comment: Очень странно что с `sort` вообще работает

Comment: @АндрейNOP вроде ничего странного. `sort` принимает функцию-компаратор и возвращает отсортированный массив. Когда мы в компараторе на любой паре элементов возвращаем `1`, он думает, что предыдущий элемент всегда больше следующего, и получается аналог `reverse`. А когда возвращаем `0`, то ничего не сортируется.

Comment: А, это компаратор, я думал что это функция-селектор, ок

Comment: С sort не везде работает, потому что stable sort никто не гарантирует. // сс @АндрейNOP

Comment: @Qwertiy "Несмотря на кажущуюся необходимость, вытекающую из названия, устойчивость совсем не обязательна для правильности сортировки и чаще всего не соблюдается, так как для её обеспечения практически всегда необходимы дополнительная память и время."

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну тут более того, дело даже не в стабильности, а в том, что алгоритм имеет право сравнить пару элементов несколько раз и один раз они могут идти в одном порядке, а другой — наоборот. По идее вообще в каких-то реализациях алгоритма сортировки такое может привести к зацикливанию

Comment: Проблема в том, что в V8 используется другой алгоритм сортировки - Timsort, который ломается, когда компаратор отдает константу

Comment: Чёрт, да хорош уже! Надеюсь ваш вариант 38 символов не защитают! (шутка :))

Comment: @АндрейNOP Хыхы, у меня блин из-за этого работа встала =)

Comment: *из-за специфичного алгоритма сортировки* — зря вы это написали, стандарт как-то определяет какой алгоритм сортировки должен использоваться движком? А если у меня будет своя реализация JS и `sort` будет сортировать пузырьком, то ваш код зациклится :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP во-первых, как раз на пузырьке ничего не зациклится. Во-вторых, как-то не очень сравнивать "свою реализацию JS" с движком Mozilla. Firefox занимает достаточно большую долю на рынке, именно поэтому я считаю, что данный код имеет место быть. В-третьих, что значит "зря я это написал"? Я дал людям знание, что проблема не в каком-то баге, а в конкретном алгоритме сортировки (в том числе, чтобы избежать сообщений про "stable sort" и т.п.). Возможно вас задело слово "специфичный"? Так оно вовсе не означает "плохой".

Comment: Ок, пузырек не зациклился, но зациклится сортировка вставками. Ну да ладно, я просто имею ввиду, что ваш компаратор возвращает одно и то же значение для пары (a, b) и для пары (b, a),  что само по себе уже неоднозначность

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript, 54

```js
f=a=>a.reduce((c,n,i)=>c.concat(i%2?n:n.reverse()),[])

console.log(f([[4, 3, 2, 1], [5, 6, 7, 8], [12, 11, 10, 9], [13, 14, 15, 16]]));
```

Comment: Если без использования `const`, то получается 54 :)

Comment: как скажешь )))

Answer (score 9):

## Python, <s>62</s> 61

Пока ничего лучше варианта с рекурсией не придумал :)

```
f=lambda m,x:m and(x&1and m.pop(0)or m.pop(0)[::-1])+f(m,x+1)
```

https://ideone.com/i2d0f6

Answer (score 8):

## F#, 68

```
let rec f=function|[]->[]|h::t->List.rev h@(t|>List.map List.rev|>f)
```

https://ideone.com/S6PhEZ

Answer (score 7):

## PowerShell, 51

```
$f={$args[0]|%{if(++$i%2){[Array]::Reverse($_)}$_}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY5LCoNAEET3nmIWbZzBRmx/SQQXuUK2ImKg/YAYGSVBjGefaI4QqEXVowpqfL5ZTy33vTFQZytUuplyv/jYa1dL14XODtSa37SuliJN7/za6yyhVBuU22ZZ8BCZOEEtpIwwxABJoZAxJnjGy2FpR4Tk4/WXQqQIKUZKlDrWu7yG53kZWSrL@eOD4/U8NHNrzBc)

Comment: С Новым Годом !

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, <s>93</s> 91

```
function f($a){foreach($a as$v)$r[]=$_++&1?$v:array_reverse($v);return array_merge(...$r);}
```

https://ideone.com/XsiPap

Answer (score 7):

## C#, 62

```
dynamic s(int[][]a)=>a.SelectMany((x,i)=>i%2>0?x:x.Reverse());
```

https://repl.it/repls/EmbarrassedHalfCommand

Comment: судя с вопроса функция должна принимать двумерный массив!)

Comment: Массив массивов - это надмножество двумерных массивов :) В нашем случае `int[][]` тоже можно назвать двумерным массивом. Мне кажется, в этом и прикол код гольфа - использовать разные трюки, чтобы сделать код короче :)

Comment: @Yaroslav Кстати, кое-кто тоже вместо того, чтобы вернуть массив ("судя с вопроса"), вернул List<T>. И стоит отметить, его за это никто не минусовал! ;)

Comment: согласен ;) ) )

Comment: @Groxan, тем не менее, функция не примет на вход int[,] так как не сможет его неявно преобразовать => int[,] и int[][]- это 2 разных типа => на вход все таки нужно принимать int[,], а уже внутри, если вам удобно, кастовать в int[][]. Я бы уточнил у ТСа правила.

Comment: @iluxa1810, я думаю, что это непринципиально, потому что во многих языках вообще такого `[,]` нету, есть только `[][]` (да и вообще нет массивов в привычном понимании, есть только списки)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ну это читерство=). Так как решение через [][] короче благодаря LINQ.

Comment: @iluxa1810, ну почему читерство? это допускается правилами, вы можете выбрать тот или иной вариант, который выгоднее вам. Цель всего этого — чисто развлекательная :)

Answer (score 6):

## PHP,  <s>138</s> 105

```
function f($a){foreach($a as$i=>$y){foreach($y as$x=>$w){$r[]=$i&1?$w:array_reverse($y)[$x];}}return $r;}
```

https://3v4l.org/DgDi8

Comment: По сути это не является отдельной, новой функцией, и в результат должен получиться одномерный массив, а не двумерный.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie исправил

Comment: кстати, можно не ставить пробел между return и переменной, допустимо `return$r;`

Answer (score 6):

## C#, <s>188</s> 184

```
List<T> S<T>(T[,]a){var l=new List<T>();int m=a.GetLength(1);for(int i=0;i<m;i++){if((i+2)%2==0)for(int j=m-1;j>=0;j--)l.Add(a[i,j]);else for(int j=0;j<m;j++)l.Add(a[i,j]);}return l;}
```

[Тест на deck.net](https://deck.net/2c020eb2577e73f718005ead7e6ccb97)

Comment: Вариант №2 не работает - он просто сортирует вход по возрастанию. Вот пример (изменены входные данные): https://deck.net/d4e69aa13bd2563a6bcb987de9658203

Answer (score 6):

## C#,<s>171</s> <s>168</s> <s>163</s> 153

Так как решения через **LINQ** уже были, то предлагаю вашему вниманию традиционных подход.

Минифицированная версия:

```
T[]F<T>(T[,]a){var d=a.GetUpperBound(1);var r=new List<T>();for(int i=0;i<=d;i++){var b=i%2>0;int j=b?0:d;while(j<=d&j>=0){r.Add(a[i,j]);j=b?++j:--j;}}return r.ToArray();}
```

Удобночитаемая:

```
    static T[] F<T>(T[,] a)
    {
        var d = a.GetUpperBound(1);
        var r = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= d; i++)
        {
            var b = i % 2 > 0;
            int j = b ? 0 : d;
            while (j <= d & j >= 0)
            {
                r.Add(a[i, j]);
                j = b ? ++j : --j;//Трюк, что бы сэкономить символы на if/else
            }
        }
        return r.ToArray();
    }
```

---

Чуть чуть подправил:

```
T[]F<T>(T[,]a){var d=a.GetUpperBound(1);var r=new List<T>();for(int i=0;i<=d;i++){var b=i%2>0;int j=b?0:d;while(j<=d&j>=0){r.Add(a[i,b?j++:j--]);}}return r.ToArray();}
```

Удобночитаемая:

```
 T[] F<T>(T[,] a)
    {
        var d = a.GetUpperBound(1);
        var r = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= d; i++)
        {
            var b = i % 2 > 0;
            int j = b ? 0 : d;
            while (j <= d & j >= 0)
            {
                r.Add(a[i, b ? j++ : j--]);
            }
        }
        return r.ToArray();
    }
```

---

Опять чуть подправил:

```
T[]F<T>(T[,]a){var d=a.GetLength(1)-1;var r=new List<T>();for(int i=0;i<=d;i++){var b=i%2>0;int j=b?0:d;while(j<=d&j>=0)r.Add(a[i,b?j++:j--]);}return r.ToArray();}
```

Удобночитаемая:

```
T[] F<T>(T[,] a)
{
    var d = a.GetLength(1) - 1;
    var r = new List<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= d; i++)
    {
        var b = i % 2 > 0;
        int j = b ? 0 : d;
        while (j <= d & j >= 0)
            r.Add(a[i, b ? j++ : j--]);
    }
    return r.ToArray();
}
```

---

И еще чуть-чуть убрал все лишнее:

```
T[]F<T>(T[,]a){int d=a.GetLength(1),g=0;var r=new T[d*d];for(int i=0;i<d;i++){var b=i%2>0;int j=b?0:d-1;while(j<d&j>=0)r[g++]=a[i,b?j++:j--];}return r;}
```

Удобночитаемый:

```
    T[] F<T>(T[,] a)
    {
        int d = a.GetLength(1), g = 0;
        var r = new T[d * d];
        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
        {
            var b = i % 2 > 0;
            int j = b ? 0 : d - 1;
            while (j < d & j >= 0)
                r[g++] = a[i, b ? j++ : j--];
        }
        return r;
    }
```

Comment: можно уменьшить до 162

Comment: @Yaroslav, Например, что?

Comment: первая и предпоследняя строка

Comment: @Yaroslav предпоследнюю увидел. А в первой вы имеете в виду, что я могу в одну строку объявить и инициализировать переменные?

Comment: неа, я имею виду что можно убрать преобразование в массив

Comment: @Yaroslav, тогда не будет соответсвовать условиям же, по идее.=(

Comment: List почти тоже одномерный массив

Comment: Ну тогда мне проще IEnumerable возвращать через yield=) Не нужен буфер, не нужен каст и т д

Comment: можно и так, только код компактней от этого не станет

Comment: @Yaroslav, почему? Станет. 1) Не нужен будет return 2) не нужен будет буфер. Другой момент- это все таки не массив. Нужно уточнить...

Comment: @Yaroslav, теперь, наверное, я максимально сократил все.

Comment: может и так) теперь точно все

Answer (score 6):

## Perl 5, 81

```
sub f{foreach$row(@_){foreach$val(@$row){push@$s,$i++%2?@$val:reverse@$val;}}$s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BDoIwEEX3nmIWNSlhFhYFlcbYBbcgxFQtgQSlaSkuCGfHFhMXs3hv/ky@VqZLF2cVFHKQeV64l1aGL9bdoZ7q3ij5aIjpP1Tcoj@PsqMi2GjSzjaCWCRtHG@Tqwi73KhRGatW4PNMLJ8XIZMnXICWB4Q9QoLAKoQyRcgQjginQCxo5meHcF6FjzJ/wXyOZVXEN9q07wF@PaGm/mvEly8)

Answer (score 5):

## Groovy, 42

```
f={i=0;it.each{it.reverse i=!i}.flatten()}
```

https://ideone.com/XirvAC

Comment: Очень интересненький вариант)

Answer (score 4):

## C, 97

```
int f(int n,int a[n][n],int*b){for(int i=0;i<n;i++)for(int j=0,k=n;j<n;j++)*b++=a[i][i%2?j:--k];}
```

Проверить можно здесь: https://ideone.com/gkk7Di.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 63

```
def f(a,x)a[0]?(x%2==0?a.shift.reverse: a.shift)+f(a,x+1):[]end
```

https://ideone.com/T0MECG