# Гольф-код. Египетская пирамида (вид сверху)

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, строки, любой-язык, соревнование

**Условие**

Египетские пирамиды — это архитектурные сооружения, которые были характерны для древнего Египта и служили важными монументами и местами захоронения фараонов и других высокопоставленных особ. Египетские пирамиды являются одними из самых известных и загадочных архитектурных сооружений в истории человечества. Особенностью такой пирамиды считают её геометрическую форму, с определёнными углами, где в качестве материала использовались блоки.

Вам необходимо реализовать **функцию**, которая принимает в себя высоту пирамиды, возвращая карту высот из натуральных чисел для квадратной пирамиды в виде строки.

**Входные данные**

- Высота пирамиды — натуральное число от `1` до `9`. Указывает, сколько уровней должна иметь пирамида

**Выходные данные**

- Строка, содержащие в себе пробелы, переносы, натуральные числа от `1` до `9` в структуре квадратной пирамиды

**Контрольный пример**

```bash
Вход: 1
Выход:
1

Вход: 2
Выход:
1 1 1
1 2 1
1 1 1

Вход: 3
Выход:
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 2 3 2 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

**Критерий оценивания**

Применяются [стандартные правила вопросов-соревнований](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/code-golf).

Любой язык программирования.

В соревновании победит самое короткое по символам решение в виде минимизированной функции. Пробелы и переносы считаются символами. Символы считаются только в теле функции (с первого символа не являющиеся переносом или пробелом), не учитывается внешняя обёртка (инициализация библиотек и т.д.). Действуют принципы честной игры. Изменено: **объявление функции входит в подсчёт символов.**

На данный вопрос будет открыт конкурс на 100 баллов репутации. Ответ победителя будет вознаграждён.

Ответ, набравший наибольшее количество голосов на момент конца соревнования, будет принят как верный.

Ответ автора вопроса не будет фигурировать при выборе победителя.

**Срок соревнования - 10 дней. Конец 20.10.2023 в 14:00 по МСК.**

---

P.S.

Просьба указывать язык в [заголовке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#headers) ответа и количество символов минимизированной функции через запятую.

Таблица лидеров ([код формы результатов взял отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/892196/470029))

```js
execute("ru.stackoverflow.com", "1545054");
```

```css
.cssload-container,.cssload-cube{width:97px;height:97px;transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container,.cssload-cube,.cssload-half1,.cssload-half2{transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container{position:relative;margin:23px 84px;perspective:292px}.cssload-cube{animation:cube 11.5s forwards infinite;transform-origin:center 49px}.cssload-half1,.cssload-s1{top:0;transform-origin:50% 100%}.cssload-half1{height:39px;position:absolute;animation:half-fold 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-side{width:19px;height:19px;background:#ddd;position:absolute}.cssload-s1{left:39px;animation:s1ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s2,.cssload-s3,.cssload-s4{left:39px;transform-origin:50% 0}.cssload-s2{top:19px;animation:s2ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s3{top:39px;animation:s3ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s4{top:58px;animation:s4ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s5{left:19px;top:19px;transform-origin:100% 50%;animation:s5ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s6{left:58px;top:39px;transform-origin:0 50%;animation:s6ani 11.5s forwards infinite}@keyframes cube{0%,30%{transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}60%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}65%,70%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(180deg)}75%,80%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(1turn)}90%{transform:rotateX(0) rotate(0) rotate(0)}}@keyframes s1ani{0%{opacity:1;transform:translateY(0);background:#ddd}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(-90deg);background:#ddd}90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}@keyframes s2ani{0%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%,80%{background:#b4b4b4}65%{opacity:1;background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s3ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}20%,90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%{background:#969696}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s4ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%,to{opacity:0}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(90deg);background:#b4b4b4}80%{background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(90deg)}}@keyframes s5ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(-179deg)}20%{opacity:1;background:#ddd;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(90deg)}55%{background:#ddd}60%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{transform:rotateY(90deg);opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s6ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(179deg)}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(-90deg);background:#ddd}60%,80%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(-90deg)}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes half-fold{0%,50%{transform:rotateX(0)}60%,90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}
```

```html
<script src="https://mayorovp.github.io/codegolf/table-8c505e68f1349e4c69e7.js"></script>
<div class=cssload-container><div class=cssload-cube><div class=cssload-half1><div class="cssload-side cssload-s1"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s2"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s5"></div></div><div class=cssload-half2><div class="cssload-side cssload-s3"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s4"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s6"></div></div></div></div>
```

---

## Результаты

### **По условиям соревнования:**

- **1 Место**, [@extrn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/324712/extrn), [Haskell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1545175), **55 символов!**
- **2 Место**, [@tim-vyazovick](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/569503/tim-vyazovick), [Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1546275), **96 символов!**
- **3 Место**, [@qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy), [Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1546275), **100 символов!**

Победителю соревнования вручается приз в размере 100 репутации.

---

### По голосам

- **1 место**, [@qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy), [HTML без скриптов и текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1545535), **12 голосов!**
- **2 Место**, [@extrn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/324712/extrn), [Haskell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1545175), **11 голосов!**
- **3 Место**, [@aepot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373567/aepot), [C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1545543/470029), **7 голосов!**

Ответ победителя по голосованию отмечен как верный.

---

Всем спасибо за участие! Представленные ответы вызывают восторг!

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149059/discussion-on-question-by-acinit------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: А вы будете новогодний конкурс устраивать? У вас интересные задания получаются: вроде и простые, а попробуй сделай это в 55 символов :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## HTML без скриптов и текста, <s>3955</s> <s>3849</s> 2318

Входные данные задаются количеством отмеченных чекбоксов.

К сожалению, тут разметка задаёт использование счётчиков.
В более длинном решении ниже такого нет.

```css
* { font-weight: normal }
body { counter-reset: i }
tr { counter-increment: i; counter-reset: j }
tr:nth-child(n + 10) { counter-increment: i -1 }
tr > * { counter-increment: j }
tr > :nth-child(n + 10) { counter-increment: j -1 }
th::before { content: counter(i) }
td::before { content: counter(j) }

tr, th, td { display: none }

#a:checked ~ * :first-child,
#b:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(2), :last-child),
#c:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(3), :nth-last-child(2)),
#d:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(4), :nth-last-child(3)),
#e:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(5), :nth-last-child(4)),
#f:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(6), :nth-last-child(5)),
#g:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(7), :nth-last-child(6)),
#h:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(8), :nth-last-child(7)),
#i:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(9), :nth-last-child(8)) {
  display: revert;
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox id=a checked disabled><input type=checkbox id=b checked><input type=checkbox id=c checked><input type=checkbox id=d><input type=checkbox id=e><input type=checkbox id=f><input type=checkbox id=g><input type=checkbox id=h><input type=checkbox id=i>
<table>
  <tr><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th></tr>
  <tr><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><th><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><th><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td></tr>
</table>
```

Минифицированная версия:

```html
<input type=checkbox id=a checked disabled><input type=checkbox id=b checked><input type=checkbox id=c checked><input type=checkbox id=d><input type=checkbox id=e><input type=checkbox id=f><input type=checkbox id=g><input type=checkbox id=h><input type=checkbox id=i><table><tr><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th></tr><tr><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td></tr><tr><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td></tr><tr><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td></tr><tr><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td><td></tr><tr><td><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td><td><td></tr><tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr><tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr><tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><th><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr><tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><th><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr><tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><td><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr><tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td><td><td><td></tr><tr><td><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td><td><td></tr><tr><td><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td><td></tr><tr><td><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td><td></tr><tr><td><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td><td></tr><tr><td><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><td></tr></table><style>*{font-weight:400}body{counter-reset:i}tr{counter-increment:i;counter-reset:j}tr:nth-child(n+10){counter-increment:i -1}tr>*{counter-increment:j}tr>:nth-child(n+10){counter-increment:j -1}th::before{content:counter(i)}td::before{content:counter(j)}td,th,tr{display:none}#a:checked~* :first-child,#b:checked~* :is(:nth-child(2),:last-child),#c:checked~* :is(:nth-child(3),:nth-last-child(2)),#d:checked~* :is(:nth-child(4),:nth-last-child(3)),#e:checked~* :is(:nth-child(5),:nth-last-child(4)),#f:checked~* :is(:nth-child(6),:nth-last-child(5)),#g:checked~* :is(:nth-child(7),:nth-last-child(6)),#h:checked~* :is(:nth-child(8),:nth-last-child(7)),#i:checked~* :is(:nth-child(9),:nth-last-child(8)){display:revert}</style>
```

### Более интересное решение, 3849

```css
div { --c: j; counter-increment: i; counter-reset: j }
div:nth-child(n+10) { counter-increment: i -1 }
x { counter-increment: j }
x:nth-child(n+10) { counter-increment: j -1 }
x::before { content: counter(var(--c)) " " }

div, x { display: none }

#a:checked ~ * :first-child,
#b:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(2), :last-child),
#c:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(3), :nth-last-child(2)),
#d:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(4), :nth-last-child(3)),
#e:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(5), :nth-last-child(4)),
#f:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(6), :nth-last-child(5)),
#g:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(7), :nth-last-child(6)),
#h:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(8), :nth-last-child(7)),
#i:checked ~ * :is(:nth-child(9), :nth-last-child(8)) {
  display: revert;
}

div:is(:nth-child(1), :nth-last-child(1)) > :nth-child(n+1):nth-last-child(n+1),
div:is(:nth-child(2), :nth-last-child(2)) > :nth-child(n+2):nth-last-child(n+2),
div:is(:nth-child(3), :nth-last-child(3)) > :nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(n+3),
div:is(:nth-child(4), :nth-last-child(4)) > :nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(n+4),
div:is(:nth-child(5), :nth-last-child(5)) > :nth-child(n+5):nth-last-child(n+5),
div:is(:nth-child(6), :nth-last-child(6)) > :nth-child(n+6):nth-last-child(n+6),
div:is(:nth-child(7), :nth-last-child(7)) > :nth-child(n+7):nth-last-child(n+7),
div:is(:nth-child(8), :nth-last-child(8)) > :nth-child(n+8):nth-last-child(n+8),
div:is(:nth-child(9), :nth-last-child(9)) > :nth-child(n+9):nth-last-child(n+9) {
  --c: i;
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox id=a checked disabled><input type=checkbox id=b checked><input type=checkbox id=c checked><input type=checkbox id=d><input type=checkbox id=e><input type=checkbox id=f><input type=checkbox id=g><input type=checkbox id=h><input type=checkbox id=i>
<main>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
  <div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div>
</main>
```

Минифицированная версия:

```html
<style>div{--c:j;counter-increment:i;counter-reset:j}div:nth-child(n+10){counter-increment:i -1}x{counter-increment:j}x:nth-child(n+10){counter-increment:j -1}x::before{content:counter(var(--c)) " "}div,x{display:none}#a:checked~* :first-child,#b:checked~* :is(:nth-child(2),:last-child),#c:checked~* :is(:nth-child(3),:nth-last-child(2)),#d:checked~* :is(:nth-child(4),:nth-last-child(3)),#e:checked~* :is(:nth-child(5),:nth-last-child(4)),#f:checked~* :is(:nth-child(6),:nth-last-child(5)),#g:checked~* :is(:nth-child(7),:nth-last-child(6)),#h:checked~* :is(:nth-child(8),:nth-last-child(7)),#i:checked~* :is(:nth-child(9),:nth-last-child(8)){display:revert}div:is(:first-child,:last-child)>:nth-child(n+1):nth-last-child(n+1),div:is(:nth-child(2),:nth-last-child(2))>:nth-child(n+2):nth-last-child(n+2),div:is(:nth-child(3),:nth-last-child(3))>:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(n+3),div:is(:nth-child(4),:nth-last-child(4))>:nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(n+4),div:is(:nth-child(5),:nth-last-child(5))>:nth-child(n+5):nth-last-child(n+5),div:is(:nth-child(6),:nth-last-child(6))>:nth-child(n+6):nth-last-child(n+6),div:is(:nth-child(7),:nth-last-child(7))>:nth-child(n+7):nth-last-child(n+7),div:is(:nth-child(8),:nth-last-child(8))>:nth-child(n+8):nth-last-child(n+8),div:is(:nth-child(9),:nth-last-child(9))>:nth-child(n+9):nth-last-child(n+9){--c:i}</style><input type=checkbox id=a checked disabled><input type=checkbox id=b checked><input type=checkbox id=c checked><input type=checkbox id=d><input type=checkbox id=e><input type=checkbox id=f><input type=checkbox id=g><input type=checkbox id=h><input type=checkbox id=i><main><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div><div><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x><x></x></div></main>
```

Comment: Мои глаза (X_X)

Comment: @aepot, у меня есть мысли по сокращению, но пока запутался...

Comment: красивое, мне нравится

Comment: Мегахорош, очень красиво.

Comment: Мне кажется, перспективно было бы избавиться от `</x>`. Сделать или `<x/>` или даже `<x>` (не уверен на счёт второго). Ну и `</main>`, наверное, не нужен.

Comment: Можно заменить `<div></div>` на `<p> </p>`, а блочность задать через `display-type`

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, да, уже подумал про закрывающий тег - должно решаться тегом `<td>`. Смозакрывающиеся теги в html не работают. `</main>` можно выкинуть, вместе с `}</style>` если поставить его в конец. Ещё `main` можно переименовать в `m`, но в общем-то это уже мелочи. У `<p>` есть margin по умолчанию - не уверен, что окупится его обнуление.

Comment: `div` не только в HTML, но и много раз упоминается в CSS, так что сколько-то всё равно будет выигрыш.

Answer (score 13):

### Haskell, 55 <s>64</s> <s>66</s>

```hs
f n|u<-show$div(10^n)9^2=unlines[(:" ").min x=<<u|x<-u]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hr6bURrc4I79cJSWzTMPQIC5P0zLOyLY0LyczL7U4WsNKSUFJUy83M0@hwtbGprSmwka3NPZ/biJQwMpKwdNfQUOTC8yzVSgoLQkuKVLQSFOw1PwPAA)

Answer (score 9):

### Python, 100 <s>101</s> <s>102</s> <s>115</s>

По классике, я первый

```py
def f(h):q=range(1,h*2);return'\n'.join(' '.join(str(h-max(abs(h-i),abs(h-j)))for j in q)for i in q)
```

Использование

```py
height = int(input("Введите высоту пирамиды (от 1 до 9): "))
result = f(height)
print(result)
```

Терминал:

```
Введите высоту пирамиды (от 1 до 9): 5
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1
1 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 4 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 4 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 1
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

---

**За рекомендации по сокращению спасибо [@n1tr0xs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/368899/n1tr0xs), [@Глеб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/559342/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1)!**

Comment: Красивый однострочник.

Comment: @Глеб я думаю, что можно и лучше...

Comment: @Глеб ну а теперь не однострочник, получается

Comment: осталось убрать квадратные скобки; пробелы перед словами `for`; `,0` в вызове `max(abs(h-i),abs(h-j),0)`

Comment: Можно на еще одну букву сократить, если в начале добавить `a = abs` и заменить все `abs` на `a`.

Comment: @Глеб пробовал, получается столько же символов

Comment: Кстати, можно убрать пробел после `return`, он не обязателен.

Answer (score 9):

## Javascript, <s>106</s> 105

```
n=>(n*=2," ".repeat(n-1)+"\n").repeat(n-1).replace(/ /g,(m,i)=>Math.min(1+i%n,1+i/n|0,n-i%n-1,n+~(i/n))+m)
```

```js
f=n=>(n*=2," ".repeat(n-1)+"\n").repeat(n-1).replace(/ /g,(m,i)=>Math.min(1+i%n,1+i/n|0,n-i%n-1,n+~(i/n))+m)
for(q=1;q<10;++q)console.log(f(q))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100vh}
```

Answer (score 9):

### Python, 82 <s>85</s>

```py
def f(n):r=str((10**n//9)**2);return'\n'.join(' '.join(map(min,r,x*17))for x in r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc2xDgIhEITh3qfYjl1CvEML4xnfxOYSQTG5gayYnE@PYpzqq@Yv73rP2Ld2DZEiQyY9P6sy@9FaDMNRrN3JSUN9KcwFZvvICWzoj2UuvCQ4dav1B5GYlVZKIJXWjZ9n3AJ750eZNvRd0YTKPef6p7QP)

Comment: Крутая идея, даже несколько крутых идей! Что интересно, не прокатит в языках без длинной арифметики, например, в js для девятки последняя цифра теряется, чуть-чуть не хватает точности

Comment: @АндрейNOP 12345678987654321 < 2^63, так что дело не то, чтоб в длинной арифметике. Языки, которые не смешивают целые и дробные в одну кашу, справятся :)

Comment: Великолепно!!!!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Благодарю. Я выложил это, как пояснение к моему решению на Haskell. Ну и надеялся, что это даст буст более коротким решениям. Но эффект получился обратный, либо просто всем надоело :)

Answer (score 7):

### Delphi xe4, 275

```pascal
function f(n:Integer):string;var i,j,v:integer;s,q,w:string;begin for I:=0to n-1do begin v:=n-i;for J:=0to n-1do begin if(i>0)and(j>0)and(i+1-j>0)then inc(v);w:=(v-j).ToString+' ';q:=IfThen(j=0,v.ToString+' ',w+q+w);end;q := q+#10#13;s:=ifthen(i=0,q,q+s+q);end;Result:=s;end;
```

Вот читаемый вариант:

```pascal
function f(n: Integer): string;
var
  i, j, v: Integer;
  s, q, w: string;
begin
  for I := 0 to n - 1 do
  begin
    v := n - i;
    for J := 0 to n - 1 do
    begin
      if (i > 0) and (j > 0) and (i + 1 - j > 0) then
        inc(v);
      w := (v - j).ToString + ' ';
      q := IfThen(j = 0, v.ToString + ' ', w + q + w);
    end;
    q := q + #10#13;
    s := ifthen(i = 0, q, q + s + q);
  end;
  Result := s;
end;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7):

## C#, 194

```
string f(int n){int i,j,r=n-1,v;string s="",q ="",w,l="\n";for(i=0;i<=r;i++){v=n-i;for(j=0;j<=r;j++){if(i>0&&j>0&&i+1-j>0)v++;w=(v-j)+" ";q=(j==0?v+" ":w+q+w);}s=i==0?l+q+l:l+q+s+q+l;}return s;}
```

Вот более читаемый вариант:

```
string f(int n)
{
    int i, j, r = n - 1, v;
    string s = "", q = "", w, l = "\n";
    for (i = 0; i <= r; i++)
    {
        v = n - i;
        for (j = 0; j <= r; j++)
        {
            if (i > 0 && j > 0 && i + 1 - j > 0)
                v++;
            w = (v - j) + " "; q = (j == 0 ? v + " " : w + q + w);
        }
        s = i == 0 ? l + q + l : l + q + s + q + l;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Java, 410

Пожалуй, очень уж перемудрил, но что есть, то есть.

#### Идея

Каждая строчка в пирамиде является палиндромом. Значит достаточно вычислить первую часть строки, а вторая часть строки — перевёрнутая первая часть

Точно так же и со всей пирамидой: вторая часть пирамиды есть перевёрнутая первая часть.

#### Код

1. Нечитаемый вариант функции:

```java
String f(int h){int l=1+(h*2-1)/2;String[]e=new String[l];Arrays.fill(e,"");int m=1;int c=1;for(int i=0;i<l;i++){for(int j= 0;j<l;j++){e[i]=e[i]+" "+c;if(c<m)c++;}e[i]+=new StringBuilder(e[i].substring(0,e[i].length()-1)).reverse().toString();e[i]+="\n";m++;c=1;}String s=String.join("",e);e[e.length - 1]="";s=s.substring(0,s.length()-1);s+=new StringBuilder(String.join("",e)).reverse().toString();return s;}
```

2. Полный код (читаемая функция + использование):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CreatingPyramid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите высоту пирамиды (число от 1 до 9):");
        int higthOfPyramid = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Пирамида:");
        CreatingPyramid creating = new CreatingPyramid();
        System.out.println(creating.create(higthOfPyramid));
    }

    String create(int hight) {
        int length = 1 + (hight*2 - 1) / 2;
        String[] lines = new String[length];
        Arrays.fill(lines, "");
        int maxNumber = 1;
        int currentNumber = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++){
                lines[i] = lines[i] + " " + currentNumber;
                if(currentNumber < maxNumber) currentNumber++;
            }
            lines[i] += new StringBuilder(lines[i].substring(0, lines[i].length() - 1)).reverse().toString();
            lines[i] += "\n";
            maxNumber++;
            currentNumber = 1;
        }
        String result = String.join("", lines);
        lines[lines.length - 1] = "";
        result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
        result += new StringBuilder(String.join("", lines)).reverse().toString();
        return result;
    }
}
```

#### Проверка

[image: запуск кода]

#### Другой вариант использования функции

Самые крутые используют функцию так (правда этот код в онлайн-компиляторах скорее всего запускаться не будет, ибо тут графический интерфейс):

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

..........

public static void main(String[] args) {
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.cancelButtonText", "Отмена");
    Integer[] options = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int higthOfPyramid = (Integer)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
            "Какая будет высота пирамиды?", "Выбор высоты", 
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[2]);

    CreatingPyramid creating = new CreatingPyramid();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ваша пирамида:\n" + 
            creating.create(higthOfPyramid), "Результат",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}

............
```

На выходе получается это:

[image: выбор высоты пирамиды (я выбрал 9)]

[image: вывод пирамиды в диалоговое окно]

Comment: Ничего себе ты интегрировал решение из прошлого гольфа...

Comment: Кстати, у меня онлайн-счётчик символов насчитывает в "нечитаемом" решении 430 символов, а не 432.

Comment: @Byb да, вы правы, там 430 символов, а не 432

Comment: @Byb спасибо за замечание! Ещё убрал `public`, получилось 425 :)

Comment: @Acinit не зря же прошлый гольф был совсем недавно :)

Answer (score 7):

## Java, 156

Минимизированный вариант:

```java
String f(int h){int n=h*2-1;String s="";for(int i=0,k=0;i<n;++i,k=(i<h)?i:h-i%h-2){for(int j=0;j<n;++j){s+=(j<=k?j+1:j<n-k?k+1:n-j)+" ";}s+="\n";}return s;}
```

Читабельный вариант:

```java
String f(int h) {
    int n = h * 2 - 1;
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < n; ++i, k = (i < h) ? i : h - i % h - 2) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            s += (j <= k ? j + 1 : j < n - k ? k + 1 : n - j) + " ";
        }
        s += "\n";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: [Работает!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz1a3.png)

Comment: Для автора [правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/883223): правки чужих сообщений - механизм для исправления орфографии/пунктуации/оформления. Если у вас есть идеи, как улучшить ответ, то либо войдите и оставьте комментарий, либо опубликуйте своё решение.

Comment: Хм, интересно, ещё и анонимным пользователем предложена) Идея хорошая, особенно с `var` вместо `String`. Тем не менее, правку правильно отклонили, да и я тоже своё решение поправлять не буду - как решил изначально, так пускай и будет, без подсказок)

Comment: В развёрнутом варианте можно переменные более понятно назвать. Односимвольные переменные жутко смотрятся.

Comment: @Зонтик, да, согласен, для развёрнутого можно переназывать, но в данном случае мне кажется, что названия переменных практически естественные. `h` - высота, `n` как замена высоты по формуле - вполне. `i`, `j`, `k` - стандартные однобуквенные названия переменных цикла. Ну и строка `s`, но её тоже незачем называть как-то иначе)

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3.8+, <s>108</s> 100

```
lambda n:[r:=range((n:=2*n-2)+1),'\n'.join(' '.join(str(1+min(i,j,n-i,n-j))for j in r)for i in r)][1]
```

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##PY1BDsIgEEX3PcXsylhqpG4MCSepXWAUhdiBTNl4ekQ0Ln7yFi/vp1d@RDqeEpfiwMDTrperBdIza8OW7jchSJtpR@OEg0LZn6nfh@hJ9PCDLbNQw1rJyyBp9HUB0UWGAJ6AG/ovLrNaui6xpyxq619zghA@HjWvPSupDohYyhs)

```
f = lambda n:[r:=range((n:=2*n-2)+1),'\n'.join(' '.join(str(1+min(i,j,n-i,n-j))for j in r)for i in r)][1]
    
print('\n\n'.join(f(n) for n in range(1,10)))
```

Старая версия (108): [tio.run](https://tio.run/##XY2xCgIxEET7fMV2yXo5MWcn@Cc2goluwMmx5gq/PuZQFCwGhsfwZn7WW8G@tUtMlBz4YAjHaYNxMqSxLgp7gt3mInCWPuVR1YXh3pv47DFKT2ZORSmTgPSMa3QYwpvJHzNmVkF13fx1r9@0jvEbBx92zNzaCw)

```py
def f(n):
 n=2*n-2
 return'\n'.join(' '.join(str(1+min(i,j,n-i,n-j))for j in range(n+1))for i in range(n+1))
    
print('\n\n'.join(f(n) for n in range(1,10)))
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на то, что пробелы в начале строки не учитываются. так что старое решение 106 (или 107, не уверен), а не 108. Ну и, так как я сам шел по очень похожему пути, могу сказать, что можно короче. :)

Comment: @extrn, странное правило, что эти пробелы не учитываются, ведь без них не будет работать... Короче пока не придумал, зато придумал длиннее на html xD

Comment: "Символы считаются только в теле функции **(с первого символа не являющиеся переносом или пробелом)**". Видимо чтобы поставить в равные условия языки с обязательными отступами и без. А любой прогресс это хорошо - куда-нибудь да приведет! :)

Answer (score 7):

### C#, 107

С объявлением (107)

```cs
using static System.Math;
```

```cs
string f(int n){var s="";for(int i=-n,j;++i<n;s+='\n')for(j=-n;++j<n;)s+=n-Max(Abs(i),Abs(j))+" ";return s;}
```

Без объявления (117)

```cs
string f(int n){var s="";for(int i=-n,j;++i<n;s+='\n')for(j=-n;++j<n;)s+=n-Math.Max(i<0?-i:i,j<0?-j:j)+" ";return s;}
```

---

Linq с объявлениями, по фану (115)

```cs
using static System.Math;
using static System.Linq.Enumerable;
using static System.String;
```

```cs
string f(int n)=>Join('\n',Range(1-n,n*2-1).Select(i=>Join(" ",Range(1-n,n*2-1).Select(j=>n-Max(Abs(i),Abs(j))))));
// или так
string f(int n){var x=Range(1-n,n*2-1);return Join('\n',x.Select(i=>Join(" ",x.Select(j=>n-Max(Abs(i),Abs(j))))));}
```

Ещё нашел альтернативу `Max(Abs(i),Abs(j))` - `Sqrt(Max(i*i,j*j))`, но это ровно столько же по символам.

Comment: Замена `string` на `var` сделает короче. Если функцию заменить на лямбду, то ещё короче.  Если `i` и `j` объявить в одном цикле, то ещё 2 символа. После `for` лишний пробел. Не уверен, разрешают ли правила выкинуть `Math.` и потребовать `using static` вне считаемого размера (но ведь в коде всё равно `Math`, а не `System.Math`); а если да, то замена условных операторов на min может тоже что-то дать.

Comment: Фигурные скобки можно выкинуть поместив добавление перевода строки в постусловие.

Comment: `for(int i=1,j;...for(j=1;...` даст -2. `s+=Math.Min(...)+" "` даст -3.

Comment: @Qwertiy обновил уже

Comment: Ага, отлично получилось)

Comment: Пытался return выкинуть и сделать через linq - получается 105: `(int n)=>Join("\n",Range(1-n,2*n-1).Select(i=>Join(" ",Range(1-n,2*n-1).Select(j=>n-Max(Abs(i),Abs(j))))))` - сократить лучше не вышло. Другие 2 варианта длиннее: `(int n)=>{Func<Func<int,dynamic>,dynamic> s=Range(1-n,2*n-1).Select;return Join("\n",s(i=>Join(" ",s(j=>n-Max(Abs(i),Abs(j))))));}` & `(int n)=>{var r=Range(1-n,2*n-1);return Join("\n",r.Select(i=>Join(" ",r.Select(j=>n-Max(Abs(i),Abs(j))))));}`.

Comment: Ссылка на песочницу не влезла в коммент: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##jZK7TsMwGIX3PIWVpTa5tGGs4yCEYEB0oQNLFzc4ra32j2I7iKrqswcnvQBqCvVi65wjf8eX3ES5kU1TGwkLNN0YK9bxi4SKenvJWG5l/tOJH6FeC83nK9EfmnC77HemVjuReh5CTzXkqQQbukgrZqhADGGnICAsey4lYH8GfvjKYSFwEkF4ewNRQuKpWIncYnkMocsZxTKIJvwT388NliRsJ0W6Qb3h8J8O284/hd43wNcyz04LZNgFMNXC1hrQ9ynMr77mz2a7a7p9cI30Gf8crPvuS19zQa6G63HAo@KA7sCG@T4tSt1pkjm8okEgU6AmYIMZDEhrKmc4WTmZOL0F2WXc0mQ6uovkWIaqXaixIoGrdSxv6M7z3Ab701YsoahKkxFFQVARb@s@z0MJplyJ@E1LK9yfFLjAVfumfZaTd03zBQ).

Comment: `-n+1` -> `1-n`

Comment: Вот бы в linq как-то не дублировать `Range(1-n,n*2-1).Select`, но я ничего не придумал...

Answer (score 7):

### Groovy, 117

```
def f(n){s=n*2-1;a=new int[s][s];n--;(0..n).each{r=n-it..n+it;r.each{i->r.each{a[i][it]++}}};a*.join(' ').join('\n')}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 96

```
def p(h):r=range(1-h,h);return'\n'.join(' '.join(str(h-max(abs(i),abs(j)))for j in r)for i in r)
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python, 121

Минимизированный вариант:

```
def f(h):
    q=range(1,h*2);l=lambda x:x//h*(h-x%h*2)+x%h;return'\n'.join(' '.join(str(min(l(i),l(j)))for j in q)for i in q)
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python, 190

Минимизированный вариант:

```
def b(h):
    s=2*h-1;p=[[0]*s for i in range(s)]
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(s-2*i):
            for k in range(s-2*i):
                p[i+j][i+k]+=1
    return'\n'.join(' '.join(list(map(str, p[i])))for i in range(s))
```

Comment: А зачем два ответа? Можно было в один засунуть оба решения. Примеры см. выше, так все делают.

Comment: В одно сообщение вроде бы помещают два варината одного решения: сокращенное и полное.  Или два разных решения, то же в одно сообщение?

Comment: Да, простите, сразу не разглядел. Если у вас разные решения — то, конечно, в разные сообщения. Правда, непонятно, зачем второе.

Answer (score 6):

## php, 113

```
function p($n){$l=$c=$n*2;$x="";while(--$c){$r=$l;while(--$r)$x.=" ".min($c,$r,$l-$r,$l-$c);$x.="\n";}return$x;}
```

Полный

```
function p($n){
   $l = $c = $n * 2; 
   $x = "";
   while (--$c) {
       $r = $l;
       while (--$r) $x .= " " . min($c, $r , $l - $r, $l - $c);
       $x .= "\n";
   }
   return $x;
}
```

Comment: Функция должна возвращать строку, не выводить. Заранее +

Comment: @extrn оу, спс. поправлю счас

Comment: @extrn грусть как выросло в размере :(

Comment: я ожидал что код вырастет на размер return, потому, что `$x.=` по длине совпадает с `echo`, но вот про то, что после `return` еще что-то стоять должно - забыл :) тем не менее, пробел после `return` лишний.

Comment: да, а выросло еще на объявление переменной. Если нотисы/варнинги отключить, то можно не объявлять, конечно )

Comment: Мне кажется, что вариант с выводом тоже стоило бы сделать допустимым. не во всех языках есть возможность сформировать строку перед выводом за разумное количество действий. Вон решение на html - там и функций нет. Стоит уточнить у автора конкурса.

Answer (score 6):

### Python, 124

```
def p(x):
 a,y='',[]
 for i in range(x):y[i:x*2-i-1]=[i+1]*(x*2-i*2-1);a+=' '.join(map(str,y))+'\n'
 return a+a[::-1][x*4-1:]
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 180

Вот вариант, с рекурсией:

```py
def r(l):
 def p(l,s=1):
  r=range(l)
  return[[s if n in(0,l-1)or i in(0,l-1)else p(l-2,s+1)[n-1][i-1]for i in r]for n in r]
 return'\n'.join(' '.join(map(str,r))for r in p(l*2-1))
```

**PS:** Пирамиду высотой в 7, этот код уже не выводит, слишком долго...

Comment: Ну, пробелов можно понаубирать много, станет где-то  530, а так идея и реализация очень интересные.

Comment: "слишком долго" - ожидаемо, с такой-то сложностью алгоритма. но не против правил. долго - но не бесконечно :)

Answer (score 5):

### Python, 141

```py
import numpy,re
def p(x):
 a=numpy.full([x*2-1]*2,1)
 for i in range(2,x+1):a[i-2+1:x*2-i,i-2+1:x*2-i]=i
 return re.sub(r'[^\d\n]',' ',str(a))
```

Comment: Можно сократить, если добавить строчку `from numpy import full` и в тексте функции соответственно ссылаться на numpy уже не надо будет. И после return пробел можно убрать. Итого -7 символов.

Comment: @Глеб можно не `from numpy import full`, а `from numpy inport *`

Comment: и да, `print(p(9))` не учитывается в подсчёте символов, это использование функции

Comment: а с учётом изменений выше, должно получится `154` символа

Comment: хотя вижу, что можно еще меньше